# How to send POST request to test the api Rest using ARC extention or ANGULAR5?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, spring-data

I'm trying to test the api rest in spring boot , so i'm using the ARC extention to send a POST request but i guess i'm doing it wrong .

After authentication i get the token that i use to test the api rest .

so here is the method in spring boot :

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/saveProjectToClient",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean saveProjectToClient(@RequestBody DTO dto){
        System.out.println("Person id  : "+dto.getIdPerson());
        System.out.println("Project id : "+dto.getIdProject());

         return true;
    }
```

this method is not doing anything but showing the id , i'll change that after it works ..

For ARC extention : 
[image]

To send the parameter in body  :

[image]

As you can see i get an error :

```
   {
"timestamp": 1526330389396,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message": "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of long out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of long out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1134a39; line: 1, column: 1]",
"path": "/saveProjectToClient"
}
```

What's the problem ? i'm using the post request in incorrect way ? or the method in spring boot is not well written ?

**EDIT**

Angular5 Service using HttpClient :

```
addProjToClient(idPerson:number,idProject:number){
    if(this.authService.getToken()==null) {
      this.authService.loadToken();
    }

    return this.http.post(this.host+"/saveProjectToClient", {
  idPerson,
  idProject,
}, {headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authService.getToken()})})

  }
```

**Problem** : Now when i try to call this method by the angular5 service , i don't get any result and even more no errors , the method in spring boot is unreachable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is clearly stated in the exception message:

`Can not deserialize instance of long out of START_OBJECT`

Jackson cannot deserialize a long when it finds a starting `{` character in your JSON request body. Wrapping the id in a model like the following should suffice:

```
public class MyModel {

    private Long id; // use primitive type if, as I would think, id cannot be null

    public void setId( Long id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

You then obviously have to tell Spring to use the custom model as the `@RequestBody`:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/saveProjectToClient", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public boolean saveProjectToClient( @RequestBody MyModel model ) {
    System.out.println( "ID: " + String.valueOf( model.getId() );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you were absolutely right , i tested this with 2 variable as i need two , it's working well using arc extention , but now when i move to angular 5 it's not working , i've updated the post if you can see it again .

Comment: I know little to none about Angular, but from what I see you are sending two fields in the request body (`idPerson` and `idProject`) without any key associated with them. You also absolutely **have** to check if string concatenation `this.host + "/saveProjectToClient"` results in the correct URL to be called. Also, check the log, it's impossible to not have an error there.

Comment: There is no problem with the url I've checked it right now , i tried also to send the request this way : {idPerson : 'idPersone' , idProject : 'idProject } , and also no error no results , this is really hard to debug as i can't see any errors or exceptions

Comment: The JSON you posted is wrong. Either way, post a different question as I don't have enough space to answer in the comments (also mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your problem).